# Xposed unable to install after minor CM update

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-3, clockworkmod-recovery, xposed-framework

I just updated Cyanogenmod from *CM-11-20151122-NIGHTLY-i9300* to *CM-11-20151130-NIGHTLY-i9300* on my Galaxy S3. After completion the usual Xposed reinstall was no longer possible:

<sup>Click on the image to enlarge</sup>
[image: Xposed error]

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime5startEPKcS2_"
referenced by "/data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/cache/app_process"...
```

The changelog does not state related changes. This error has never occurred to me. I only changed the recovery from Clockworkmod to TeamWin.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it is an exact consequence, but you may want to read the latest from the developer about Xposed Framework at [http://www.xda-developers.com/wanam-xposed-pulled-out-of-play-store/](http://www.xda-developers.com/wanam-xposed-pulled-out-of-play-store/), dealing with Samsung devices.

Comment: Try refering to this link. [**Xposed for android 4.4.4 not working anymore + FIX**](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-android-4-4-4-t3249895)

Comment: @Pamur Hey, thanks for the suggestion on this ancient question. I don't even remember If or how I solved it.